# Action decorator kwargs not passed on when retrieving the view with "as_view" method on a ViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In one app, I have the following `ViewSet`:

```
class MyViewSet(MyGenericViewSet, ListModelMixin):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=["post"], accepted_renderers=(MyJsonRenderer,))
    def custom_action(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do some stuff here
```

`MyViewSet` is routed with a `DefaultRouter`. I need to specify `MyJsonRenderer` because it comes second in my `DEFAULT_RENDERERS` setting (I have an HTML renderer first) and this particular action is not meant to be used with a web browser. It works fine when I hit the routed URL with a POST request, and always returns JSON content.

However I also need to adapt my site to an old AJAX API, so in another `adapter` app, I have the following function-based view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax(request, *args, **kwargs):
    custom_action_view = MyViewSet.as_view({"post": "custom_action"})
    return custom_action_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If my request does not specify that it is expecting JSON content in its header or params, content negotiation fails because the default HTML renderer is used (`500 Internal Server Error`). The action is performed on the server but the response is not rendered.

How can I make the view obtained with `as_view` to use the proper renderer class ?

Comment: can you add the error traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`@renderer_classes(MyJsonRenderer)`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/decorators.py#L81-L85) decorator to specify the renderer class to use with a function based view.

If you need to pass the renderer into your `MyViewSet.as_view()` call, then you can specify `renderer_classes=(MyJsonRenderer,)` in the call, i.e. `MyViewSet.as_view({"post": "custom_action"}, renderer_classes=(MyJsonRenderer, ))`.   [The `as_view()` function accepts a list of keyword arguments to override several view settings.](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L49)

Comment: Mmmh good idea I had not tried that, but doing this raises an exception so I don't think the `**initkwargs` argument are meant to be used like this, they are passed to the constructor of the class. However maybe I can override that constructor and make an instance limited `accepted_renderers` attribute... I'll try this.

Comment: Oh no actually `initkwargs` can override the ViewSets' class attributes, and the correct class attribute is not `accepted_renderers` but `renderer_classes`. With `renderer_classes=(MyJsonRenderer,)` it does work ! Thanks a lot, modify your answer and I will accept it.